# Per-project flake8 max line length?

Tags: python, git, flake8

I'm using a Flake8 git hook in my project and I want to relax the line length limit, but only for one project. Given that it looks like there's no clear API for that, how do I modify this hook to do that? Alternatively, is there a git-config setting or an environment variable that would let me set that? Here's the hook source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import logging
import os.path as P

from flake8.main import git


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ret = git.hook(
        strict=git.config_for('strict'),
        lazy=git.config_for('lazy'),
    )
    if ret:
        sys.exit(ret)
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Use the `setup.cfg` file in each project. This file is read by various Python-related tools, including pep8 (see [pep8's documentation](http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html)) and flake8.

The documentation for `setup.cfg` with `flake8` is in the [Configuring Flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html) chapter. In short, you want a `setup.cfg` file with this content (obviously, adjust the 99 to your needs):

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 99
```

If you don't want to create a `setup.cfg` file, you can also specify this as an argument to the command:

```sh
flake8 --max-line-length 99
```

Comment: Where does this config go when using `tox` and a `pyproject.toml`? It can go in the command line invocation in the `tox.ini` but is it possible to put it separately in the `tox.ini`? And if your `tox` config is in the `pyproject.toml` does the `flake8` config have to go in the `tox.ini` text inside the `pyproject.toml` or can the `pyproject.toml` have it's own section that `flake8` will read when invoked by `tox`?

Answer (score 2):

Supplement post for @Matthieu Moy's answer.

If you use `pyproject.toml`, install [pyproject-flake8](https://github.com/csachs/pyproject-flake8) package which enables you to write your flake8 settings:

```
[tool.flake8]
max-line-length = 88
```

If you use `tox.ini`, add the following line to your config file:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 88
```

Be aware that multiple configuration files will override each other. In my case, the tox config overrides the poetry config.